# winform awesomium embedding scripts and images

Tags: winforms, resources, web-controls, awesomium

I have a winforms application which basically has only an awesomium webcontrol inside (similar to native winfroms webcontrol)

I also have a web application (ASP.net) which contains around 20 javascript files, few stylesheets and images.

The web app is hosted online (cloud server).

My goal is to somehow optimize the winforms loading time (loading the website) by embedding the images, scripts and stylesheets in the winform itselt, and keeping the html and C# code online.

That means, my html pages(online) need to reference the scripts, images and stylesheets from the winform resources.

I know how to embed files in winforms, but i cannot seem to figure out how to reference them in the html.

Much thanks